# Webpage pops out of webview in Xamarin App

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webview, xamarin.android

When loading a webpage into the webview it shows correctly, but when I click on a menu item (on the web page inside the webview) it pops outside of the webview.  Here is the code I'm using to load the webpage into the webview.  How do I prevent this from happening.

BTW, the links are all normal links:

```
            <a href="....">Menu Item</a>

            localWebView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webview);
            localWebView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            localWebView.Settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
            localWebView.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
            localWebView.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;
            localWebView.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;                
            localWebView.LoadUrl("https://...");
```

Comment: what are the menu items?  Just simple links?  Or do they have the target attribute set?  Or are they opening windows with js (which you have explicitly enabled in your setup)?

Comment: the links are simple links

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add a WebViewClient and it works now.

```
    localWebView.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

    public class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        [Obsolete("deprecated")]
        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
        {
            view.LoadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
```